# Talend Lookup value

Tags: talend

i've got the following problem.

I've created a time dimension with different values, for example (Date format dd.mm.yyyy):

```
ID - FULL_DATE  - ... - WEEK_FIRST_DAY_DATE
1  - 01.01.1900 - ... - 01.01.1900
2  - 02.01.1900 - ... - 01.01.1900
.. - ...        - ... - ...
7  - 07.01.1900 - ... - 01.01.1900
```

Instead of the date in WEEK_FIRST_DAY_DATE i need the value of the column ID

Output desired:

```
ID - FULL_DATE  - ... - WEEK_FIRST_DAY_DATE
1  - 01.01.1900 - ... - 1
2  - 02.01.1900 - ... - 1
.. - ...        - ... - ...
7  - 07.01.1900 - ... - 1
```

I guess i could solve that problem with a lookup but i dont know how i can implement it in my job.

My job has the following element: tRowGenerator - tMap - tFileOutputDelimited
[image: Job elements]

My tMap component looks like this:

[image: tMap Component]

How can i achieve that lookup on the first column?

Comment: I cant understand what you have and what you want, please give us your input and the desired output, and i ll be happy to help you.

Comment: i will edit the question

Comment: i have updated the question and added the input and the desired output, thx for the advice